# org.json.JSONObject exception on a valid json string

Tags: java, json, org.json

I have the following code:

```
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
    ...
} catch(JSONException ex) {
    if(LOGS_ON) Log.e(TAG, "Could not save data.", ex);
}
```

It throws an exception, although the json string passed in is pretty valid. The exception is the following:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"ShopId3Digit":"ww0","ServerTime":1426695017191,"SMSTelephone":"2104851130","SendPODAgain":true,"SendLocationAgain":true,"IsHUB":false,"AllowReceiptsAndDeliveries":true} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Do you see something wrong with the json data I'm passing in?

BTW this is the string as seen in Eclipse watch:

```
"{\"ShopId3Digit\":\"ww0\",\"ServerTime\":1426695017191,\"SMSTelephone\":\"2104851130\",\"SendPODAgain\":true,\"SendLocationAgain\":true,\"IsHUB\":false,\"AllowReceiptsAndDeliveries\":true}"
```

Comment: try using JSONParser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake after all. I obtain the data from a .NET program through Newtonsoft serializer. By mistake I was serializing the already serialized object resulting in just a string. The starting and ending quotes in the watch in Eclipse are actually part of the value.

Thank you godfatherofpolka for the effort you went through.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working version

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "{\"ShopId3Digit\":\"ww0\",\"ServerTime\":1426695017191,\"SMSTelephone\":\"2104851130\",\"SendPODAgain\":true,\"SendLocationAgain\":true,\"IsHUB\":false,\"AllowReceiptsAndDeliveries\":true}";

    try {
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
      System.out.println("Success: json = ");
      System.out.println(json.toString(2));
    } catch(JSONException ex) {
      System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
    }
  }   
}
```

(using the most recent version available at https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java). I have tested this code, it compiles and successfully outputs

```
Success: json = 
{
  "IsHUB": false,
  "SMSTelephone": "2104851130",
  "AllowReceiptsAndDeliveries": true,
  "SendPODAgain": true,
  "SendLocationAgain": true,
  "ShopId3Digit": "ww0",
  "ServerTime": 1426695017191
}
```

Therefore, the error seems to be not with the json data.

Comment: I'm using the version that comes with Android SDK. I even tested with the string hard-coded as you did, but I'll recheck tomorrow. I might forgot something.

Comment: Something else is happening. When I try it hard-coded it works.

Comment: @alfoks Please provide more code and information on how you obtain the json data? Can you create a minimal, self-contained example in which the error occurs?

Comment: It was my mistake after all. I obtain the data from a .NET program through Newtonsoft serializer. By mistake I was serializing the already serialized object resulting in just a string. The starting and ending quotes in the watch in Eclipse are actually part of the value.